# Importing (Requiring) Ruby class from irb

Tags: ruby, irb

In Python, importing classes, methods, variables etc to the python shell is done by `import MyClass`. I was to do the same thing in the Ruby shell. I have the following code:

```
module Search
   class ApartmentSearch
       attr_accessor :hood, :minPrice,
                     :maxPrice, :bed,
                     :bath

       def initialize(hood = "",
                   minPrice = 0,
                   maxPrice = 0,
                   bed = 0,
                   bath = 0)
           @hood = hood
           @minPrice = minPrice
           @maxPrice = maxPrice
           @bed = bed
           @bath = bath
      end
   end
end
```

I can import the module into the Ruby shell by `require '/path/to/module/search`, but when I then try to create a new `ApartmentSearch` object by calling `Search.ApartmentSearch.new()`, I get the following error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'ApartmentSearch' for Search:Module`, which is obvious to some degree because `ApartmentSearch` is a class, not a method. What am I doing wrong here? My goal is to have classes kept modular and imported where needed.

Comment: you want to do: `Search::ApartmentSearch.new()` and not `Search.ApartmentSearch.new()`

Comment: Ah, that worked perfectly. I didn't find that when I was searching the docs but I guess I recall from using something like Net:HTTP.method

Comment: @bjhaid: Your comment should be an (accepted) answer ☺︎

Comment: @Johnsyweb then you owe me an upvote :) I am posting it as an answer so the OP can accept

Comment: @ChrisClouten posted as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want to do:

```
Search::ApartmentSearch.new() and not Search.ApartmentSearch.new()
```

`ApartmentSearch` is in the `Search` namespace as modules in ruby can be used for namespacing